# How to level a sloping concrete slab with a 2” difference?

Tags: concrete, flooring, foundation, subfloor, self-leveling-concrete

I know this sounds bad and I need to give some backstory to not sound off the alarms... I’m going to give the main question first and then backstory below so you know I’m not crazy.

**Question:**

We have roughly a 10’ x 10’ area on a semi-basement/semi-walkout-level of our house that slopes 2” down from one end to the far corner. This was carpeted and we are now refinishing with luxury vinyl planks, but we want the subfloor to be level and get rid of this crazy dip. Self-leveling compound seems only good for a 1” dip? Can we do several layers of self-leveling concrete? Should we try to frame up and pour concrete or is there an easier/better approach?

**Backstory:**

Shortly after we moved into our house (now 4 years ago) we noticed a sloping corner of the house with all the furniture now out of the house. We weren’t sure how we or the home inspector missed this, but we were afraid of the worst with foundation issues after we noticed this. Still, a lot of things didn’t add up for it to be an immediate concern, so we waited until this year to get it checked.

Long story short - it was determined by foundation repair engineers that there *are* no active foundation issues. The house was completely renovated 15+ years ago and that gives a lot of evidence that the house at one point was either sinking or settled badly, but that it was corrected and stabilized and not moved in the last 15 years. We spoke to the prior owners and the home builder that did this renovation and it all checked out. The engineers drilled holes into the slab and put an endoscope below the sloped section to confirm that there was no gap between the slab and the soil below. We asked about mud-jacking or raising the house up with piers, and they said that was unnecessary... And even if foundation work was needed, there would be no raising the level of the house since that would create a bunch more issues with all the new stuff built into the house after the renovation. In other words, our house is stable, but very crooked in this corner. I asked about us filling things in on top if that would cause problems, and they said not to worry about it.

Part of this question is me not feeling comfortable doing a bunch of heavy concrete work myself and wondering if there’s another way.

Comment: Have you read the instructions on the package? The answer may be product-specific. The main reason you wouldn't do that is because there's no aggregate. The small stones and gravel give masonry much of its strength and stability. You could see some substantial cracking in a repair of that thickness.

Comment: Have you considered using lumber for the areas more than 3/4" below the high point? You could then fill the remaining area with self-leveler.

Comment: @isherwood, I haven’t purchased any self-leveler yet, but was seeing the 1” limit a lot on the online descriptions. I like the idea of using lumber, but obviously could not solely do this with lumber without making things more lumpy... how would this work exactly, put plywood down and pour self-leveler on top?

Comment: No. You'd build a floor with tapered sleeper joists.